# Failed to get D-Bus connection: No such file or directory. $XDG_RUNTIME_DIR not set. libpam-systemd installed

Tags: debian, systemd, d-bus

I installed Yunohost on a LIME2 like I did with my Pi3 and now I have the same error as two months (see "[Cannot enable user service. “Failed to get D-Bus connection: Connection refused” Support](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/415357/)"), only this time I have libpam-systemd already installed.

```
admin@Gildurklaus:~ $ systemctl --user list-units
Failed to get D-Bus connection: Connection refused
```

Again, without the user parameter, the command runs fine.

```
admin@Gildurklaus:~ $ systemctl list-units

  UNIT                                                                 LOAD   ACTIVE SUB       DESCRIPTION
  proc-sys-fs-binfmt_misc.automount                                    loaded active waiting   Arbitrary Executable File Formats File System Automount Point
  sys-devices-platform-soc-3f201000.serial-tty-ttyAMA0-hci0-rfkill1.device loaded active plugged   /sys/devices/platform/soc/3f201000.serial/tty/ttyAMA0/hci0/rfkil
  sys-devices-platform-soc-3f201000.serial-tty-ttyAMA0-hci0.device     loaded active plugged   /sys/devices/platform/soc/3f201000.serial/tty/ttyAMA0/hci0
  ...
  To show all installed unit files use 'systemctl list-unit-files'.
  lines 102-129/129 (END)
```

And again Dbus isn't running for my user, only system-wide.

```
admin@Gildurklaus:~ $ ps -ef | grep dbus
message+   574     1  0 05:53 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/dbus-daemon --system --address=systemd: --nofork --nopidfile --systemd-activation
admin     1988  1971  0 10:03 pts/0    00:00:00 grep dbus
```

And again, systemd does not appear to be running for this user

```
admin@Gildurklaus:~$ ps -ef | grep dbus
message+   574     1  0 05:53 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/dbus-daemon --system --address=systemd: --nofork --nopidfile --systemd-activation
admin     1988  1971  0 10:03 pts/0    00:00:00 grep dbus
admin@Gildurklaus:~$ ps -ef | grep systemd
root       183     1  0 05:53 ?        00:00:01 /lib/systemd/systemd-journald
root       187     1  0 05:53 ?        00:00:00 /lib/systemd/systemd-udevd
root       572     1  0 05:53 ?        00:00:00 /lib/systemd/systemd-logind
message+   574     1  0 05:53 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/dbus-daemon --system --address=systemd: --nofork --nopidfile --systemd-activation
admin     1990  1971  0 10:04 pts/0    00:00:00 grep systemd
```

And again $XDG_RUNTIME_DIR is missing.

```
admin@Gildurklaus:~ $ systemd --test
Trying to run as user instance, but $XDG_RUNTIME_DIR is not set.
```

This time libpam-systemd is installed.

```
admin@Gildurklaus:~$ apt list --installed *systemd*
Listing... Done
libpam-systemd/oldstable,now 215-17+deb8u7 armhf [installed]
libsystemd0/oldstable,now 215-17+deb8u7 armhf [installed]
systemd/oldstable,now 215-17+deb8u7 armhf [installed]
systemd-shim/oldstable,now 9-1 armhf [installed,automatic]
systemd-sysv/oldstable,now 215-17+deb8u7 armhf [installed]
admin@Gildurklaus:~$ apt list --installed *dbus*   
Listing... Done
dbus/oldstable,now 1.8.22-0+deb8u1 armhf [installed,automatic]
libdbus-1-3/oldstable,now 1.8.22-0+deb8u1 armhf [installed,automatic]
libdbus-glib-1-2/oldstable,now 0.102-1 armhf [installed,automatic]
libnih-dbus1/oldstable,now 1.0.3-4.3 armhf [installed,automatic]
```

[update]

I've noticed a subtle difference between my Pi3 and LIME2 server.
The Pi3 starts a XDG_SESSION_ID session, while the LIME2 server doesn't.

Pi3

```
admin@Yroklaus:~ $ sudo systemctl status systemd-logind.service
● systemd-logind.service - Login Service
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/systemd-logind.service; static)
   Active: active (running) since Sat 2018-03-24 15:43:32 UTC; 1h 27min ago
     Docs: man:systemd-logind.service(8)
           man:logind.conf(5)
           http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/logind
           http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/multiseat
 Main PID: 508 (systemd-logind)
   Status: "Processing requests..."
   CGroup: /system.slice/systemd-logind.service
           └─508 /lib/systemd/systemd-logind

Mar 24 15:43:32 Yroklaus systemd[1]: Starting Login Service...
Mar 24 15:43:32 Yroklaus systemd-logind[508]: New seat seat0.
Mar 24 15:43:32 Yroklaus systemd[1]: Started Login Service.
Mar 24 15:43:32 Yroklaus systemd-logind[508]: Couldn't add lingering user folatt: No such file or directory
Mar 24 15:43:32 Yroklaus systemd-logind[508]: User enumeration failed: No such file or directory
Mar 24 16:47:01 Yroklaus systemd-logind[508]: New session c1 of user admin.
```

LIME2

```
admin@Gildurklaus:~$ sudo systemctl status systemd-logind.service
● systemd-logind.service - Login Service
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/systemd-logind.service; static)
   Active: active (running) since Sat 2018-03-24 16:43:45 CET; 1h 27min ago
     Docs: man:systemd-logind.service(8)
           man:logind.conf(5)
           http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/logind
           http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/multiseat
 Main PID: 571 (systemd-logind)
   Status: "Processing requests..."
   CGroup: /system.slice/systemd-logind.service
           └─571 /lib/systemd/systemd-logind

Mar 24 16:43:45 Gildurklaus systemd-logind[571]: New seat seat0.
Mar 24 16:43:45 Gildurklaus systemd[1]: Started Login Service.
```

Answer (score 5):

> And again Dbus is running.

No, it clearly is not.  And it was not the last time, either.

Your process listing shows only the *system-wide* Desktop Bus broker.  Note the `--system` in the command arguments and the fact that the process is *not running as you*.

When you run `systemctl` with the `--user` option it talks to your per-user instance of `systemd` via *your per-user* Desktop Bus broker.

Neither is in fact running.

You'll likely find that starting up the per-user instance of `systemd` will start up the per-user Desktop Broker as well.  The former manages the latter, and the `dbus.socket` unit (from `/usr/lib/systemd/user/dbus.socket`) is likely already enabled for your per-user service manager.  (Observe that it is the *socket* unit that has to be enabled, not the *service* unit.)

So it's actually the same answer as before, even though it wasn't explicit in the last Q&A:  Make sure that your per-user instance of `systemd` is running, and make sure that that starts up your per-user Desktop Bus broker.  You can run the steps that `pam_systemd` runs by hand, to check that they themselves work in the first place.  Then check that `pam_systemd` is configured to actually be called as part of your login procedure.

And bear in mind that *`su` is not a login mechanism*.  It works *within an existing* interactive login session.  If you are not logging in as the account in question, the systemd hooks will not be activating the per-user instance of systemd for that account.

## Further reading

- Jonathan de Boyne Pollard (2014). *[Don't abuse su for dropping user privileges](http://jdebp.eu./FGA/dont-abuse-su-for-dropping-privileges.html)*. Frequently Given Answers.
- Lennart Poettering et al. (2017). [`pam_systemd`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/pam_systemd.html). *systemd manual pages*. Freedesktop.org.
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/423648/5132
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/427917/5132
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/407863/5132

Comment: How can it be the same answer as before when libpam-systemd is installed?

Comment: Because the last time you should have done what is stated here, too.  Read ¶6 again.

Answer (score 2):

`libpam-systemd`needs to be called in the PAM stack.

Run `pam-auth-update` and check that it's enabled

Comment: I get "-bash: pam-auth-update: command not found" All pam commands seem to be missing.

Comment: That's weird, is `libpam-runtime` package installed? Do you have any references to `pam_systemd.so`in files in `/etc/pam.d/`?

Comment: Looks like netpbm was missing. I installed it, reinstalled libpam-runtime, then ran pam-auth-update and checked them all to enabled. That still didn't solve my issue though.