# How do I restart dbus after manual intervention in upgrade to Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: ubuntu, d-bus, dist-upgrade

I am trying to upgrade from Ubuntu 16.04 LTS to 18.04 LTS.

No matter which upgrade command I try: `do-release-upgrade` or `apt dist-upgrade`, at some point in the upgrade I start getting numerous "Failed to connect to bus: No such file or directory" errors and eventually the upgrade process stops with an error and the following packages in error:

- udev
- gnome-bluetooth
- x11-common
- bluez
- indicator-bluetooth
- rpcbind
- unity-control-center
- xserver-common
- initramfs-tools-core
- cups-daemon
- initramfs-tools
- libxvmc1:amd64
- xserver-xorg-core
- cups-core-drivers
- xserver-xorg-video-radeon
- libxtst6:amd64
- libxtst-dev:amd64
- network-manager
- ubuntu-drivers-common
- xserver-xorg-video-vesa
- software-properties-gtk
- xserver-xorg-video-amdgpu
- postgresql-common
- xserver-xorg-video-tdfx
- libice6:amd64
- libice6:i386
- libxt6:amd64
- libxt6:i386
- gnome-session-bin
- xwayland
- xserver-xorg-input-wacom
- xserver-xorg-input-synaptics
- ghostscript-x
- xserver-xorg-video-mach64
- libaudio2:amd64
- xserver-xorg-video-ati
- pulseaudio
- xserver-xorg-video-intel
- libxt-dev:amd64
- xserver-xorg-video-r128
- libqtgui4:amd64
- gnome-settings-daemon
- mutter
- xserver-xorg-video-qxl
- metacity
- unity-settings-daemon
- libmutter-2-0:amd64
- x11-xkb-utils
- vino
- xserver-xorg-input-evdev
- gnome-session

By manually intervening (running [dpkg --configure](https://askubuntu.com/questions/103834/how-do-i-force-configuration-of-partially-installed-packages) on selected packages until all issues were resolved) I could eventually get all (remaining) packages installed and configured.

On my 3rd attempt I was able to get the furthest (by using `apt dist-upgrade`) but even then I could not properly reboot - the next reboot would start reasonably OK, but starting with "Login Service", several services would fail to start (in approximately this order):

1. Login Service (systemd-logind.service)
2. Disk Manager
3. Modem Manager (ModemManager.service)
4. Network Manager (NetworkManager.service)
5. /etc/rc.local Compatibility
6. GNOME Display Manager (gdm.service)
7. Bluetooth Service (bluetooth.service)

Even then, X11 was unable to initialise and I had no login prompt (CTRL-ALT-F1 would not give me a login prompt).

I tried [reinstalling dbus](https://askubuntu.com/questions/999042/i-cant-use-the-shutdown-command-because-the-system-failes-to-connect-to-bus-n) but that did not work. I'm wondering if the [pam_systemd was not installed](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/431896/failed-to-get-d-bus-connection-no-such-file-or-directory-xdg-runtime-dir-not) (since I was also getting D-Bus connection errors)?

Clearly I missed some required packages in the manual intervention phase. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Try update/upgrade:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
```

Purge and install again `dbus-user-session` package:

```
sudo apt purge dbus-user-session
sudo apt install dbus-user-session
```

Comment: Indeed, I have always used update/upgrade before starting. No luck. I did a purge on dbus (which removed quite a lot) and reinstalled as much as I could remember. I will try purge and reinstall the dbus-user-session.

Comment: @KevinM OK, write a comment what's happened after `dbus-user-session` package installing.

Comment: It reinstalls dbus-user-session, but the bus is still not available. A 'ps aux' shows that dbus-daemon, dbus-launch and upstart-dbus-bridge processes are running. Current errors include 'invoke-rc.d: initscript udev, action "restart" failed.' when trying to configure udev.

Answer (score 1):

I eventually gave up on this task. I have no idea what was wrong with my base 16.04 LTS installation, but an upgrade was impossible.

I finally had to install a new 18.04 LTS installation over my old one.

Comment: I am having the same issue: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1161081/systemctl-services-suddenly-timing-out Been at it for 2 days non-stop. I hope I won't have to do a fresh install.